# Exercise on the Primitive Element theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I have the following exercise:

Let $E / \mathbb{Q}$ be a finite dimensional field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

If $[E :\mathbb{Q} ]=6$ and $\mathbb{Q} \subset F_{1} \subset E, \quad \mathbb{Q} \subset F_{2} \subset E$ are subextensions with

$[F_{1}:\mathbb{Q}]=2, \quad [F_{2}:\mathbb{Q}]=3$.

Let $z_{1} \in F_{1}$ and $z_{2} \in F_{2}$ with $z_{1}, z_{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Must there exist $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that

$\mathbb{Q}\left(\lambda_{1} z_{1}+\lambda_{2} z_{2}\right)=E$.

What happens if we assume $[E :\mathbb{Q} ]=12$, $[F_{1}:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, $[F_{2}:\mathbb{Q}]=3$?

My attempt to answer was to mimic the proof of the primitive element theorem, where the fact that the base field is infinite is used, but I cannot understand how I should use the given degrees of the extensions.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: The specific degrees are irrelevant. As soon as you know that there are only finitely many intermediate extensions of a separable, finite degree field extension, you can apply the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @k.stm Thank you for the answer. So in the exercise the answer is positive in both cases? I think that using the tower law, we can see that there cannot exist any other intermediate extension. Also, can I assume wlog that  $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ are generating elements of E with respect to $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t reading carefully. The degrees *are* relevant, as the pigeonhole principle yields $ℚ(λ_1z_1 + λ_2z_2) = ℚ(z_1,z_2)$ for some $λ_1, λ_2 ∈ ℚ$ (and for this the degrees are irrelevant), but you will further need $ℚ(z_1,z_2) = E$, which is only given for $z_1 ∈ F_1$ and $z_2 ∈ F_2$ with $[F_1 : ℚ]$ and $[F_2 : ℚ]$ being coprime and multiplying to $[E : ℚ]$. (So the answer is still positive in both cases, but the degrees *are* relevant, both times.)

Comment: Thanks once again for the help.

Comment: And once again I wasn’t reading carefully. The elements $z_1$ and $z_2$ need to be generating $F_1$ and $F_2$. This is given in the first case, but not necessarily in the second case as $z_2 ∈ F_2$ could be an element such that $ℚ(z_2)/ℚ$ is of degree $2$. For example if $z_1 = \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $z_2 = \sqrt 2$, but $F_2 = ℚ(\sqrt[4] 2)$. You won’t get $E  = ℚ(\sqrt[4] 2, \sqrt[3] 2) = ℚ(\sqrt[12] 2)$ to be the same as $ℚ(\sqrt 2, \sqrt [3] 2) = ℚ(\sqrt[6] 2)$.